# "Since you persist, I tend to think that you´re not only wrong but dishonest." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When someone writes/tells me "Since you persist, I tend to think that you´re not only wrong but dishonest", what does it mean?

Is that person calling me dishonest? Is the other person being rude to me?

**Context:**

It's a part of email conversations between a buyer and a seller.The buyer(not a customer yet) wrote to me stating that a process is not working as mentioned and he seemed to be under an impression that we are tricking/forcing him to go through that process. I replied to him mentioning that the process is 'optional' to clear out his confusion. I did not force him to make a transaction or purchase throughout my reply.

On his second reply, he wrote that what I had mentioned is partially true but does not apply to him/his country. And then he wrote "Since you persist, I tend to think that you´re not only wrong but dishonest. I don't want any business with you. It was a waste of time, obviously."

I felt he was both defensive and rude with me!

Comment: Please, provide some context.

Comment: I have added the context, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you're wrong.
>
> Not only do I think you're wrong, but I think you're dishonest too.
>
> Why do I think you're wrong and dishonest? Because you're persisting.
>
> However, I can't be sure. So I *tend* to think you're wrong and dishonest.

I wouldn't say this person is being rude, but they *are* very defensive. They're defensive because you keep doing whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

No, actually he/she isn't being rude with me. 
it could be called the sentence meaning :-

> Earlier, i thought that you are only wrong 
>   But, As you have continued your work (which must be something bad)
>   I believe that you are not only wrong but, dishonest also.

Meaning of dishonest - fraud, corrupt, cheater, immoral 
In your case i believe that it's "immoral" as he/she thinks that *you* have done something bad or fraudulent.